# development server(Eclipse-Django) not loading through browser on windows

Tags: django

1)I am unable to access the website hosted by django's development server on my local machine(http://127.0.0.1:8000/).

2)I am unable to get the website in the browser.

Using Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

When you start the server, it should say something like:

```
Validating models...
0 errors found

Django version 1.3, using settings 'myapp.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Do you get this message, and is the port number the same as the one you're using?

If it is, you could possibly have a problem with proxy settings.  Does your browser have a proxy server configured?

Comment: Proxy settings are right. It was working before . It is happening on all the browsers.

Comment: Try disabling the proxy settings (i.e. "Don't use proxy") and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: could it be a firewall problem ??